# Unable to open redis 6379 for inbound on AWS EC2

Tags: amazon-ec2, amazon-web-services, php-fpm, redis

I have two servers on EC2. One hosting my php application and other hosting my redis server. I am managing my php session and data on redis server. So on my php server I gave the ip:port as session save path and got the error `FastCGI sent in stderr: "PHP message: PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught exception 'RedisException' with message 'Connection closed'`

So I search on the web and came to know that I need to open port 6379 on my redis instance for inbound traffic. I opened it by setting a custom TCP setting in AWS security group but still the port is coming closed to outside world. But I am able to listen to the port on redis server itself. Am i Missing anything in the process? Do I need to make any other change somewhere. Please guide me on this. I am very much new to AWS management
On Instance 1: I am using php-fpm, nginx and phpredis 
On Instance 2: Using Redis

Comment: Did you open port 6379 for outbound traffic on your other EC2 instance (where you run PHP)?

Comment: Seems to be some firewall issue. Its working now